# C Pointer for 2-dimensional Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Already declared is an array such as:

```
char ma[10][20];
```

The address of a specific element is gotten using:

```
p = &ma[1][18];
```

Which element will `p` point to after `p++;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding 1 to a address of member of array, get the address of the next member. since p is the address of `ma[1][18]`, which is member of the array `ma[1]`, `p+1` is the address of `ma[1][19]`. (And of course, `p++;` is like `p=p+1;`)

Edit: I assumed, of course, that p is `char*`. If it's something else, the answer can be other.

Comment: if `p` is not `char *` (or a qualified variant of `char *` or `void *`), the program is invalid, so we can safely assume it is `char *`.

Comment: Yes, but some compilers will compile it anyway. (Tested on gcc)

Comment: the fact that `gcc` compiles it doesn't make it valid, but at least the compiler has to issue a diagnostic if the type is not one of the types cited above.

Answer (score 1):

`p++` yields `&ma[1][19]`

Here is the explanation:

```
char ma[10][20];
char *p = &ma[1][18];
```

`p` value is `&ma[1][18]` which is equal to `*(ma + 1) + 18`.

So `p++` value which is equal to `p + 1` is equal to   `(*(ma + 1) + 18) + 1` equal to  `*(ma + 1) + 19` which is equal to `&ma[1][19]`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the type of `p`; assuming it's `char *`, then `p++` will advance it to `ma[1][19]` (1 char).

Here are a couple of variations:

```
char (*p)[20] = &ma[1];
```

In this case, `p` is a pointer to a 20-element array of `char`, initialized to point to `ma[1]`; executing `p++` will advance `p` to point to `ma[2]` (20 chars).

```
char (*p)[10][20] = &ma;
```

In this case, `p` is a pointer to a 10-element array of 20-element arrays of `char`, initialized to point to `ma`; executing `p++` will advance `p` to the next element immediately following `ma` (200 chars).